# What's the building Harold Meachum lives atop?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, film-location, iron-fist

Harold Meachum lives in an upper floor of an iconic Art Deco building--so described by Joy--in Manhattan. What real-life building is used in the exterior shots?

Comment: Do you have any images that you can add to your question?

Comment: An image might be very helpful identifying which building you're talking about since it would not require having watched this show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://untappedcities.com/2017/03/20/nyc-film-locations-for-iron-first-on-netflix/5/ the apartment is supposedly located at 570 Lexington Avenue, NYC (RCA Victor building). The interior is a build set.

Wiki/pics of building:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_Building

Comment: Please don't include only link. Add the part from this link which answers the question in your post. Thank you.